# Button Click event occurs when it is disabled

Tags: c#, events, button, click

I'm pretty new at C#. But have experience in C, Python etc.
here is my question.

I have a GUI which has 2 forms. 
the First form asks for a serial number of the unit and the second one is where the main test occurs.

In the 2nd form, there is a stage when I wait for the controller (DUT) to boot up so that I can get the bootup information.
I got most of the code working, but here the issue.

I disable the "Next" button until the user powercycles the unit. But, even with the button disabled, the click event occurs (when the user clicks the disabled button) and based on the number of click he does, the SW validates the clicks and skips the next stage/s.

how can I sort this out? Or, is there another better way to code this?

here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WIFI_DMX_TEST
{
    public partial class form_test : Form
    {
        int x = 0;
        int MAX_TEST_STATES = 15;                                                //Set the number of test states.
        string Rx_String;


        test_instructions test_intsructions = new test_instructions();          //Create a new instance of the class test_instructions

        public form_test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            but_test_next_Click(null, null);                                    //Call the but_test_next_Click event
            Serial_INIT();
        }

        public void but_test_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if ((x <= MAX_TEST_STATES) && (but_test_next.Enabled == true))
            {
                if (x == 0)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.check_unit;
                    //load picture here showing unit
                }
                else if (x == 1)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.connect_cables;
                    //load picture here showing cables to connect
                }
                else if (x == 2)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.powerup_unit;
                    //load picture here showing unit powerup
                }
                else if (x == 3)
                {
                    but_test_next.Enabled = false;                              //Disable the Next button

                    if (Rx_String == null)                                      //check if the Rs232 info is empty
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No DUT info available. Please powercycle the unit", "Error: No data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        while (Rx_String == null) ;                             //Sit here doing nothing and wait till info is available
                        but_test_next.Enabled = true;
                    }

                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.program_unit;           //Show next instruction.
                    //put programming function here.
                    //Put info here showing the unit has been programmed successfully or not.
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 4)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.reset_unit;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 5)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.query_colour_R;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 6)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.query_colour_G;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 7)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.query_colour_B;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 8)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.query_colour_W;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 9)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.acclerometer_mode;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 10)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.STL_mode_Sens_Low;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 11)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.STL_mode_Sens_High;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 12)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.test_mode;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 13)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.control_output;
                    //if failed, then log this error and WIFI controller info in the Log file.
                }
                else if (x == 14)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.powerdown_unit;

                }
                else if (x == 15)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = test_intsructions.disconnect_cables;

                }
                //x++;
                if (!((x == 3) && (but_test_next.Enabled == false)))
                {
                    x++;
                    //but_test_next.Enabled = true;
                }

                //but_test_next.Enabled = true;

            }
        }

        private void but_test_exit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Serial_Close();
            this.Close();
            this.Hide();
            form_startup f1 = new form_startup();
            f1.ShowDialog();

        }

        private void program_unit()
        {

        }

        class test_instructions
        {
            public string check_unit
            {
                get { return "Check DUT for any obvious faults"; }
                set { }
            }
            public string connect_cables 
            { 
                get {return "Connect cables to the DUT";}
                set {}
            }
            public string powerup_unit
            {
                get { return "Powerup the DUT"; }
                set {}
            }
            public string program_unit
            {
                get { return "Programming the DUT"; }
                set { }
            }
            public string reset_unit
            {
                get {return "Reset the unit";}
                set {}
            }
            public string query_colour_R
            {
                get { return "Is the LED RED ON?"; }
                set {}
            }
            public string query_colour_G
            {
                get {return "Is the LED GREEN ON?";}
                set {}
            }
            public string query_colour_B
            {
                get {return "Is the LED BLUE ON?";}
                set {}
            }
            public string query_colour_W
            {
                get {return "Is the LED WHITE ON?";}
                set {}
            }
            public string acclerometer_mode
            {
                get { return "Accelerometer mode: Move the unit and check if the Lights change colour" ;}
                set { }
            }
            public string STL_mode_Sens_Low
            {
                get { return "Set sensitivity to Low"; }
                set { }
            }
            public string STL_mode_Sens_High
            {
                get { return "Set sensitivity to High"; }
                set { }
            }
            public string test_mode
            {
                get { return "Press the test mode and check if lights are moving between R,G,B and W"; }
                set { }
            }
            public string control_output
            {
                get { return "Check if Control output is working as expected."; }
                set { }
            }
            public string powerdown_unit
            {
                get { return "Switch OFF the jig"; }
                set { }
            }
            public string disconnect_cables
            {
                get { return "Disconnect cables and remove DUT"; }
                set { }
            }

        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Rx_String = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.AppendText(Rx_String);
        }

        private void Serial_INIT ()
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void Serial_Close()
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }

        private void form_test_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Serial_Close();
        }

    }
}
```

cheers,
Mat

Comment: please use a switch statement instead of else if else if else if.

Comment: thanks @PhilipStuyck.
Good point. Ill look into it.
Mat

Comment: @PhilipStuyck, thanks for suggesting the switch statement . it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you mean by disabling the button.
if you did the following it should work:

```
 NextBtn.IsEnabled = false;
 NextBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Otherwise, you can simply disable the method by creating a bool:

```
bool hasOccured;
Private void Reason_Occured(EventArgs)
{

     hasOccured = true;

}

private void NextBtn_Click(Args)

{

     if(hasOccured) return;
     //code chunk

}
```

Comment: what I meant by disabling the button is to show the user that the button is there, but its disabled until they power cycle the unit.

Secondly, I can't get the methods as you described. I am using VS2013 Express.
the only methods I have available are


'code' but_test_next.enabled = false;
'code' but_test_next.visible = false

Comment: He appears to be using winforms not WPF

Comment: @LabMat. Check if the button is enabled in your click event handler, if it isn't exit it.

Comment: @Mark Hall
hi Mark, I don't understand what you are talking about. 
I am enabling and disabling the button in the click event (of that button itself)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.. I edited another option in to my answer.

Comment: @IsaacDj, 
what happens is that the SW recognizes the button being mouse clicked even when it is disabled on the screen. this in turn causes the counter in my click event to increment, hence missing certain states.
cheers Mat

Comment: I just don't see where you disabled it. Have you tried using the bool and actually disabling the method yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.

I managed to fix this issue. Seems like I had to use a Switch, Case statement rather than If statements.

Cheers for all your help

Mat
:D